# Putting Bitmap into another Bitmap with different PixelFormat

Tags: c#, bitmap, fft, complex-numbers, aforge

I have a few Bitmaps, that have a `PixelFormat` that is, say, `24bppRGB`. I know that the images that have been put in these bitmaps have an original `PixelFormat` that is `Mono8`.

I want to do FFT on these images, and as I use AForge, I need the bitmaps to have a `PixelFormat` of 8bppIndexed, to be able to pass them through `ComplexImage`.

My question is, how to put those `24bppRGBimages` in `8BPPIndexed Bitmaps` ? I have tried creating new bitmaps with the desired format and then doing `NewBitmap8bppIndexed = OldBitmap24bppIndexed`but it seems to give my new bitmaps the `PixelFormat`of the old ones.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/d7196dc6-8176-4344-a505-e7ade35c1741.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had no idea this existed. Will answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Grayscale Class](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/d7196dc6-8176-4344-a505-e7ade35c1741.htm) in the AForge Framework is the solution. Very simple to use.

Thanks to @Hans Passant for the hint.